# how to avoid rewriting java script code?

Tags: javascript, html, function

I am looking for a way to avoid rewriting the same code again and again.
I am making a web page that has divs with hide and show option, with the help of a button you toggle between hide and show. I found an easy way to achieve the effect with this code:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("myDIV");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
  This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
```

This works perfectly but gets a bit tedious when you have a dozen or more divs with said effect. Is there a way to avoid having to rewrite the function for each and every div?

Thank you! :)

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_parameters.asp

Comment: If the button is always just before the toggled div, you can refer the div by `button.nextElementSibling`.

Comment: So pass in an id to the method. Code could be simplified by just toggling a class.

Comment: Just want to add 1) don't link to w3schools 2) the entire point of a function is to reuse the code inside it

Answer (score 0):

Easy, parameterize the id:

```
function myFunction(divId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(divId);
```

and in the HTML pass the id to the function:

```
<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Try it</button>
<div id="myDIV"> ...</div>

<button onclick="myFunction('myOtherDIV')">Try it</button>
<div id="myOtherDIV"> ...</div>

... and so on ...
```

You can keep one single function and handle as many divs as you want.

Comment: Note that there are a billion "better" ways to do this, last but not least using different code, or including some libraries, etc. I kept close to the original code on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You could run the javascript function with a parameter. So you only have one function and then you only need to change the parameter name. See the example below.

```js
function myFunction(div) {
    var x = document.getElementById(div);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

  <button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Try it</button>
  <button onclick="myFunction('myDIV2')">Try it2</button>

  <div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
  </div>

  <div id="myDIV2">
    This is my DIV2 element.
  </div>

  <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the div id to a function

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    var x = document.getElementById(divId);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

> This works perfectly but gets a bit tedious when you have a dozen or
>   more divs with said effect

Create an array of such `div` ids to be toggled and iterate the same, for example

```
var divIds = ["myDIV1", "myDIV2", "myDIV3"];
divIds.forEach( s => toggleDiv(s) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a parameter into the function.

```js
function myFunction(divName) {
    var x = document.getElementById(divName);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV')">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction('myDIV2')">Try it</button>

<div id="myDIV2">
This is my DIV2 element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

using event target and operating relatively on elements, can do the task.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>
     
      <hr>
     
      <div class="wrapper">
        <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Try first</button>
        <div class="content">
           This is my DIV element.
        </div>
      </div>
     
     <hr>
     
     <div class="wrapper">
        <button onclick="myFunction(event)">Try second</button>
        <div class="content">
           This is my DIV element.
        </div>
      </div>
     
     <hr>
      
     <p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>
      <script>
         function myFunction(event) {
             var wrapper = event.target.parentElement;
             var content = wrapper.querySelector('.content');
             if (content.style.display === "none") {
                 content.style.display = "block";
             } else {
                 content.style.display = "none";
             }
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("myDIV");
    for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
       x[i].style.display = x[i].style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<body>

<p>Click the "Try it" button to toggle between hiding and showing the DIV element:</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div class="myDIV">
This is my DIV element.
</div>

<p><b>Note:</b> The element will not take up any space when the display property set to "none".</p>


</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function toggleVisibility(selector) {
    const elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    elements.forEach( element => {
        const isVisible = element.offsetHeight;
        if (isVisible) {
            element.setAttribute('hidden', '');
        } else {
            element.removeAttribute('hidden');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleVisibility('#myDIV')">Try it</button>
<button onclick="toggleVisibility('.toggle')">Try it with className</button>

<div id="myDIV">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
<div class="toggle">
    This is my DIV element.
</div>
```